# Domain pointing to one server with sub-directory pointing to another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I recently developed a new website for a customer and now it's time to put it online. However, I got one problem:

- old website currently has the domain *www.example.com*
- old website has a sub-directory that **must stay online** (*www.example.com/proj*)
- new website must be moved to *www.example.com*
- moving the *proj* directory to the new machine is not an option - different dependencies, different PHP versions, etc...

So, I need a way to point *www.example.com* to the new machine IP and to point *www.example.com/proj* to the old machine IP. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you redirect requests to `/proj` to `proj.example.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS for the example.com domain, change the record to point to the new IP. Then in the new server, make sure mod_proxy is turned on and you can add this to the server/vhost config:

```
ProxyPass /proj/ http://1.2.3.4/
ProxyPassReverse /proj http://1.2.3.4/
```

where "1.2.3.4" is the IP address of the old server.

You can do something similar using mod_rewrite in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^proj/(.*)$ http://1.2.3.4/$1 [L,P]
```